# Battery power for project

Tags: batteries

Please could someone suggest a suitable battery for a specific project.

I need to power a 40 W  12 V car headlight bulb for 10 sessions of 3 or 4 h each time, recharging after each use.

I have tested with a 7Ah battery and only got 1 hr and I am interested in the difference between the projected mathematical time and real world experience.

Also I need to provide a cost effective solution not only for the battery but also the charger as there will be multiple instances of the set up.

Comment: First calculate the power you will use...

Comment: (Almost) every car has a 12V lead acid battery. Did you think about using that one?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking to draw (40W/12V) = 3.3A for 40 hours on one charge. That is a lot of energy...  about 133Amp-hours...

Comment: Car battery or its smaller cousin for motorbikes seems like the obvious option, and probably has about the right capacity

Comment: Start with modern LED flashlight or off-road mountain bike headlight technology.  Only go to an (LED) car headlight if experiments prove nothing lower power will be sufficient.

Comment: Do you have to use a headlight bulb ? Is it incandescent, xenon or LED ? What is the purpose ? For what application is it ? Just to see, or photography, cinematography ?

Comment: It is for an artwork to be shown outdoors away from any mains power. Tried with LED and couldn't get the same effect. Shape of the bulb and quality of light is important.Bulb is incandescent halogen. Guess I could look at xenon. Are they more energy efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You need to break down the question into :

How many ampere hours do you need?

To convert 40Watts to 12 volt and ampere = I = P/U = 40W/12V = 3.33A

And to run the lamp for 4 hours you need a battery with 4h x 3.33A = 13.33A/h

So a battery with 12V and a minimum of 13.33A/h is needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes that sounds reasonable.  I think i would add a safety margin just to be sure. I tested with a 7Ah battery and only got 1hr which makes me cautious about any projection.

Comment: That's wise to add a safety margin. And I agree that some specs are a bit optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

So you need 3.3A for 4 hours and recharging in between for 10 cycle, this should do:

https://www.digikey.ie/product-detail/en/b-b-battery/BP17-12-B1/522-1014-ND/653335